# iPhone: How to read Operator Command Reply

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, openurl

I have made an application to call operators commands directly from application, it is something like

> *100#

I use this code to send command only

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:*100#"]]];
}
```

### **My problem is I don't know how to get/read the operator reply in my application**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `tel:` scheme you are leaving your app and opening an external app (in this case, the phone app). What happens after that, is out of your app and out of your control.